# Free MIDI player for Windows

Tags: windows, gratis, media-player, midi

I am experienced in sound engineering and have DAW for music creation, manipulating with midi data etc. But importing MIDI into DAW has some difficulties: if import files, I need to set an instrument on each track, manually look at program changes, note channels etc in piano roll.

So when I need  to simply preview a MIDI file, I use Windows Media Player or some other media players.

But I need some additional info for the files that I preview: number of tracks, instruments used, built-in lyrics, tempo etc. 
So maybe there is some MIDI-focused player that will show me some more information and give some flexibility in previewing MIDI files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found MidiQuickFix java program, it covers all my requirements
https://sourceforge.net/projects/midiquickfix